# What are the differences between primitives/registers/macros/tokens?

Tags: macros, tex-core, primitives, registers, token

I started learning LaTeX and these words appear a lot in both questions and answers. Do they all mean the same thing or are they different concepts?

Comment: You may want to start reading TeXbook/TeX by topic, the concepts are quite clearly explained there. // See also [package writing - Where do I start LaTeX programming? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/where-do-i-start-latex-programming?noredirect=1&lq=1) for other resources.

Comment: You can read a brief summary of TeX principles in "TeX in a Nutshell"  http://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/optex/tex-nutshell.pdf

Comment: besides *TeX in a Nutshell*, which is fairly terse, and *TeX by Topic*, which might be too verbose, you may read sections 4-10 from *TeX for the Impatient*, available at your local CTAN mirror.

Answer (score 6):

A  "primitive" is a command defined by the tex system. So for example `\hbox` if you ask tex how this is defined

```
\show\hbox
```

You get

```
> \hbox=\hbox.
l.1 \show\hbox
              
?
```

Note that the csname `\hbox` can be given a non-primitve definition. After `\def\hbox{abc}` the above would produce

```
> \hbox=macro:
->abc.
l.2 \show\hbox
              
?
```

Similarly the primitive functionality can be assigned to other names. After `\let\qqqq\hbox` then `\show\qqqq` would produce

```
> \qqqq=\hbox.
l.2 \show\qqqq
              
?
```

---

A register is a specific storage location, these are addressed by number, originally 256 of each type but etex extends this to 2^15 (over 32 thousand) and luatex extends this again.
So integer values can be stored in `\count50`, lengths (dimen(sions)) can be stored in `\dimen222` etc. Usually a format such a latex provides allocation routines so that you do not deal with numbers directly eg `\newdimen\textwidth`  makes `\textwidth` access a dimen register and the following `\newdimen` would access the next. `\show\textwidth` produces (in latex)

```
> \textwidth=\dimen116.
l.1 \show\textwidth
                   
?
```

---

A macro is a command defined by `\def` which *expands* to it' replacement text. It is defined by TeX code not part of the tex program source. After `\def\cmd{abc}`  `\show\cmd`  produces

```
> \cmd=macro:
->abc.
l.2 \show\cmd
             
?
```